# I have a problem with dictionary and the loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a code in python, that has a dictionary of words(keys) and translations (value), i need an input command that the user writes a set of word and the out put will be all words translations.(for example: the user writes: mother, door, children, and the out put will be "mutter" "tür" "kinder".
Should use "for" loop?
How should i write the "for" loop command?

```
i = input("enter key or value")

my_dict = {"name":"arash", "lname":"sui", "age":"15", "NamPedar":"betoche"}


for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if i == k:
        print(v)
    if i == v:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
#As you wanted user writes like [mother,door,children] you can store words in list by spliting with ','
lis=list(map(str,input("User Writes:").split(",")))

my_dict = {"mother":"mutter","door":"tür","children":"kinder"}


for word in lis:
    print("The translation of word",word+":",my_dict.get(word,"No Translation of this word exist"))
```

**Output:**

```
User Writes:mother,door,children,xyz
The translation of word mother: mutter
The translation of word door: tür
The translation of word children: kinder
The translation of word xyz: No Translation of this word exist
```

Let's say user enters `value` instead of `key` and you wanted to print `key` corresponds to `value` than you can try below code..

**Code:**

```
my_dict = {"mother":"mutter","door":"tür","children":"kinder"}

lis = list(map(str, input("User Enter: ").split(",")))

for word in lis:
    if word in my_dict:
        print(f"The translation of {word} is: {my_dict[word]}")
    elif word in my_dict.values():
        for k, v in my_dict.items():
            if v == word:
                print(f"The translation of {word} is: {k}")
                break
    else:
        print(f"No translation found for {word}")
```

**Output:**

```
User Enter: mother,door,children,xyz,mutter
The translation of mother is: mutter
The translation of door is: tür
The translation of children is: kinder
No translation found for xyz
The translation of mutter is: mother
```

If this approach taking more **Time complexity**.. than you can just add `{value:key}` pairs in your initial dictionary and run the 1st code.